# How to sort on a single column; OR multiple columns at once (phase 2)

Tags: tables, sorting, column-headers

**EDIT: I'm working on this page now and for the next couple of hours, so please don't bother looking at it.**

I had many outstanding suggesting when I  [**first asked this question**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7863/how-to-sort-on-a-single-column-or-multiple-columns-at-once) five weeks ago.

The question evolved into "how to show the user the way table columns will be sorted?"

I modified the page so that it now claims to show, as a confirmation, a list of the columns to be sorted; and the sort orders of those columns. Could I ask you to take a look again at  [**the page, with its huge table**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain) and tell me how you react to the solution?

**EDIT**: to make the question explicit.

My question: Can you tell, after selecting a column by clicking its header cell, what the page is going to do? How it will evolve? IOW, when you select a column for sorting, do you see a **confirmation** of your select action?

If you see the confirmation, is it completely obvious, clear, and unambiguous?

If you **don't see** the confirmation, **please tell me so**.

The page works OK in FF 3.16, Safari 5.0.3, and Chrome 12; but to be happy again, IE 8 demands that more virgins be sacrificed.

Comment: 'Please look at my design and tell you what you think' is not really a question, what exactly are you trying to find out?

Comment: @Marielle -- Thanks, I'll edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Pete This isn't a real question. UX.SE isn't the place to go if you just want feedback on your design. I recommend you visit the chat and ask there. In the future, try phrasing the question in such a way that it would be valuable to someone else in the future, although generally "Last time I asked X, here's what I did, what do you think?" will not make for a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking, except "Take a look at my design, tell me what you think". As such, there's not much I can do except describe my immediate reactions to the interface, good and bad.

**The good:**

Your interface doesn't use much vertical screen estate. That's good for users who want to compare a lot of data simultaneously. Your tooltips are explicit, even when controls are unclear (though perhaps your intended users, stockbrokers, would be familiar with your abbreviations)

**The bad:**

I have no idea how to operate that interface. I try to sort columns by clicking their headers, but nothing happens. There's no obvious 'sort' function. Also, I couldn't tell how to force ascending / descending sorts until I accidentally rested my cursor on a cryptic looking triangular... thing, at which point a helpful tooltip came up.

I had no idea what 'MAN' did until I hovered over it. It's wasn't clear that I was selecting columns for sorting when I highlight them until I accidentally switched 'MAN' to 'AUT' (auto-refresh?). It's confusing that I have to refresh the data to sort the results.

**The ugly:**

It's hard to read the table itself - you should alternate the background colours of different columns and rows to make tracing lines easier.

**Summary:**

Needs serious work communicating the sort function. Make your table more readable and look at making 'auto refresh' the default behaviour, so it becomes clear what I'm doing as I highlight the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed impresions and comments. Yes, auto-refresh should be the default; it's manual-refresh only while I'm debugging. You think background-color striping on rows ***and*** columns? I'll try that! Thank you again for your very helpful effort.

Comment: Your most useful comment by far had to do with sort. (The thing doesn't sort immediately on selecting a col head because of the possibility that the guy wants a multi-column sort. That whole idea is still a vexing UI question.) The "refresh" button should never say "refresh" or show a refresh icon; instead, it should say "Sort" or "Sort Table": *that's* what the user is interested in, not some esoteric, developer-lingo "refresh" function. So thanks again. You're a great help. That one observation was well worth the price of admission.